# Type deduction with const qualifiers failing

Tags: c++, templates, constants, template-argument-deduction

When writing a custom iterator type, I decided I want to be able to convert from const iterators to non-const iterators. I wrote the following `remove_const` function. For some reason the compiler is failing to deduce that `const P` is the same as `const int*`. The error I get from GCC 8.2 is `types 'const P' and 'const int*' have incompatible cv-qualifiers`.

Is there something in my code which is preventing the compiler from deducing correctly? Also, if there is a better way of doing what I want I would love to know.

```
template <int, typename P>
struct my_iterator { P ptr; };

using iterator = my_iterator<3, int*>;
using const_iterator = my_iterator<3, const int*>;

template <int I, typename P>
my_iterator<I, P> remove_const(my_iterator<I, const P> it) {
    return my_iterator<I, P>{ const_cast<P>(it.ptr) };
}

int main() {
    const_iterator it{ nullptr };
    remove_const( it );
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is a godbolt link with the code](https://godbolt.org/z/JTW47f)

Comment: `const int*` is `(const int)*`, not `const (int*)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `const P`, `const` is qualified on `P` directly, given `P` is `int *`, `const P` will be `int * const` (i.e. `const` pointer), not `const int *` (pointer to `const`).

You can change the code to

```
template <int I, typename PtoC>
auto remove_const(my_iterator<I, PtoC> it) {
    using PtoNC = std::add_pointer_t<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<PtoC>>>;
    return my_iterator<I, PtoNC> { const_cast<PtoNC>(it.ptr) };
}
```